# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > 'org.gradle.api.provider.Provider org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection.getElements()'

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to implement firebase in my flutter app project but getting this error. I tried different ways to remove this error but it is not removing.`Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> 'org.gradle.api.provider.Provider org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection.getElements()'`

I tried making new project on firebase and downloading new google-services.json file into my flutter project but error still remained as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the Google Services plugin in build.gradle file.
The version of the SDK should match the version specified in the Google Services plugin.
after that clean your app.

Comment: I tried this but error still didnt get resolved